# mongodb regions to use when located in South Africa

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, visual-studio

I am creating a chatrooms app and want to store my messages on mongodb database and be able to emit atleast 10 messages whenever a user enters the chatroom to have an idea of what is talked about however when trying to create a cluster the regions provided are North America, Europe and Asia and I am based in South Africa and my users will most likely be based here to, which region should I use or mongodb is not an option for me? please advice

Answer (score 0):

Azure has a [South Africa region](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/microsoft-azure/#microsoft-azure).

Aside from that, connectivity is determined not only by geographic distance but also by where the major interconnects are and the pipe size of those interconnects. The most reliable way to determine the fastest region for your particular application is to deploy actual clusters, load them up with data and measure latency/throughput.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, i will use azure to get a South African region